# How do I add a "é" to my url

Tags: rewrite, url

Look at this link

http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_de_paternit%C3%A9

Now back to this post

The link is now:
fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_de_paternité

How do I make this happen for my site?

Im on a apache.

Comment: Hallo Admins, Look at your link, now back to mine, now back at your link, now back to mine, sadly your link isn't mine, but if your link stopped using french wikipedia it could pretend that it was mine. look down, back up. where are you? you are on wikipedia, with the accented é your e could look like. whats that in your hand, back at me, I have it, its a page with two links to that thing you love, now look again, the links are now diamonds. everything is possible when your page looks like serverfault and not wikipedia. I'm on apache.

Comment: Best. Comment. Ever. ;)

Answer (score 4):

It is being done by the browser, not by the website.

In firefox you can turn it off, read more about this at the [network.standard-url.encode-utf8](http://kb.mozillazine.org/network.standard-url.encode-utf8) documentation. It also has a reference to [RFC3987](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3987.txt) which requires browsers to do this properly. Apparently IE and Opera are not doing it properly, unless they have been fixed since the Mozillazine article was written.

So the bottom line is: when you write %C3%A9 in your browser address bar, the browser will turn it into utf-8 characters.

Answer (score 1):

[RFC3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) (specifically section 2.3) states that you can't have accented characters in a valid url.

Comment: Well you don't use special chars, you use %C3%A9 which are all valid and things like that to get around it. There are thousands of site doing it and google indexes the url properly.